# How do I remove all trailing characters from a dataframe that are equal to a letter 'h'

Tags: python, pandas

I have an output generated by another script that due to a bug is using the letter `h` as a padding character. For this reason, its become difficult to clean the generated output.

The output generated is:

```
k,g,h,kl,l,k,l,m,l,k,l,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h

g,j,k,lm,l,mn,m,l,k,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h

f,f,f,e,g,h,f,fe,dc,c,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h

ghk,h,gf,gh,g,g,k,k,jh,k,l,lm,lm,kj,lm,h,jkl,k,j,kj,h,gf,f,g,g,g,gh,g,fe,def,fe,f,fg,gf,fe,de,d,d,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h
```

How do I remove all the trailing `,h` from each row/string? Its has to be last or trailing `h` as the letter `h` appears in the middle of the string also which is part of the output and should not be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html#pandas-series-str-rstrip):

```
df['vals'] = df['vals'].str.rstrip(',h')
```

```
                                      vals
0              k,g,h,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk
1  g,j,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g
2                f,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f
3                 ghk,h,gf,l,lm,lm,kjk,j,f
```

---

`df` used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'vals': [
        'k,g,h,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h',
        'g,j,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g,h,h',
        'f,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h',
        'ghk,h,gf,l,lm,lm,kjk,j,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h']
})
```

```
                                         vals
0  k,g,h,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h
1  g,j,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g,h,h
2  f,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h
3   ghk,h,gf,l,lm,lm,kjk,j,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

s = '''k,g,h,kl,l,k,l,m,l,k,l,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h

g,j,k,lm,l,mn,m,l,k,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h

f,f,f,e,g,h,f,fe,dc,c,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h

ghk,h,gf,gh,g,g,k,k,jh,k,l,lm,lm,kj,lm,h,jkl,k,j,kj,h,gf,f,g,g,g,gh,g,fe,def,fe,f,fg,gf,fe,de,d,d,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h'''

s = [re.sub('(?:\,h)+$','',x) for x in s.split()]

for line in s:
    print(line)
```

Output

```
k,g,h,kl,l,k,l,m,l,k,l,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk
g,j,k,lm,l,mn,m,l,k,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g
f,f,f,e,g,h,f,fe,dc,c,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f
ghk,h,gf,gh,g,g,k,k,jh,k,l,lm,lm,kj,lm,h,jkl,k,j,kj,h,gf,f,g,g,g,gh,g,fe,def,fe,f,fg,gf,fe,de,d,d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = "k,g,h,kl,l,k,l,m,l,k,l,l,j,l,j,k,hg,hg,fg,hk,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h"

list2 = "g,j,k,lm,l,mn,m,l,k,lm,l,l,kl,kj,hg,hg,f,h,kh,j,h,g,g,g,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h"

list3 = "f,f,f,e,g,h,f,fe,dc,c,f,f,f,f,e,g,h,h,hg,gf,f,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h"

list4 = "ghk,h,gf,gh,g,g,k,k,jh,k,l,lm,lm,kj,lm,h,jkl,k,j,kj,h,gf,f,g,g,g,gh,g,fe,def,fe,f,fg,gf,fe,de,d,d,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h,h"

print(len(list1))
if list1[-1] == 'h' and list1[-2] == ',':
    list1 = list1[:-2]

print(len(list1))
```